# Is 'flagging' an appropriate response for someone who doesn't have authority/longevity to vote to close?

Tags: discussion, flagging, vote-to-close

Maybe I'm wrong, but [this post appears to be not a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/what-is-your-favourite-slang-expression). I do not have the rep to do so, and also haven't done it before. I think it will likely sort itself out. But would flagging a post like this to draw attention be appropriate, or would that be excessive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I felt obliged to chime in because I disagree with the answers previously posted.

When you click on the 'flag' button you are presented with a list of options as to why you flagged it.  One option is "It doesn't belong here" with a sub-menu letting you select from the same (or similar) list that you get when voting to close (off-topic, not constructive, etc.).

I would argue that since someone bothered to code in that menu in the first place, flagging a question to get moderator attention that it should be closed *seems* perfectly appropriate.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. I'm not a mod, but I have enough rep to use the "mod tools" which show me flagging activity, for example, and in many cases allow me to endorse or reject. Which I certainly don't see as burdensome. Unless the mods are actually complaining, I think we should just assume any features are there to be used. Perhaps the situation was different a couple of years ago.

Comment: Only recently 10k users had the ability to review the post's flags. Before, those flags were only visible to moderators; now, 10k users can see the flags that don't use a custom reason.

Answer (score 3):

No, it really isn't appropriate. You're asking someone to vote *for* you by proxy. That is not what flagging is about (not to mention, the moderator's vote bypasses the community democracy since their vote is immediately binding).

**Having said that**, flagging a bit more liberally is acceptable when a site is really young precisely because there *are* very few people who can close inappropriate posts. English.SE is quickly growing past the need to do so. Flagging should be reserved for egregious cases.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up the real guts of my question. So then rather than flag a question, is it just best to allow a questionable question to be sorted out by the community, moderators?

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that it is not really a question, and voted to close it.  I am curious as to whether other people agree about this type of question.

But as for flagging, I am not sure what level you need to be to see that a question is flagged.  After 500 reputation (during beta; now [3000 reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions)), it is possible to vote to close any question, but you can't see if a question is flagged until later.

Comment: ok, i assumed that whoever votes to close is handling these correctly (assuming people agree it needs to be closed); it just seemed that for someone like me to flag it (just because i cant vote to close) seemed extreme

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Robert.

The main reason I think it isn't appropriate is that it circumvents the system. If the admins/community came to the conclusion that more people should have input on closing questions, they should just lower the rep threshold for that.

That said, I think a comments suggesting a reason that it might be closed is probably a more appropriate action if you feel a burning desire to get your 2 cents in regarding a particular item.